# publish .net core app server/client to aws

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker

I would like to know how can i publish my .net app to aws using docker. from where to start which courses will be a good  starting point for me. web is fluid with a lot of unfiltered data. please help me to make sense for all this issue. from the creation till production. Thanks a lot

Comment: "web is fluid with a lot of unfiltered data" StackOverflow is part of the web with the same unfiltered data.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do it. Here's a [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/) on doing it using ECS Fargate.

One difference that you might want if you don't want to use API Gateway is that you would use an Application Load Balancer in front of your ECS Service.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick replay, is this? tutorial relevant for publishing .net application ?

Comment: It's relevant to running a service on a docker container. what is in the container is up to you, I'm sure you can find a tutorial on how to containerize a .net app.